# Show total items cshtml MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How show count items results in index cshtml, have a paginatedlist guide microsoft mvc

count results in query

```
var totalregistros= _context.users.Tolist()
return view(totalregistros)
```

the problem return in view have a pagination

```
return View(await PaginatedList<users>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
```

i need example that show

[image]

i need this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `TotalItems` or similar `int` property to your `PaginatedList` class, populate it with the count, and then display that. Additionally, the tutorial from Microsoft shows how to add page counts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-paging-to-students-index

Also, you are returning a `List<users>` to your view as the view model. Don't do that. Return a view model that has all of the properties that you want to display, including total count, etc.